# Date formatting error in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to run the below command in Unix. It doesn't work for the below date:-

```
$ date "+%m%d%Y" -d "09-Mar-2014 02:06:28"
  date: invalid date `09-Mar-2014 02:06:28'
```

When i change the command slightly, it works.

```
 $ date "+%Y%m%d" -d "09-Mar-2014 03:06:28"
 20140309
```

Can some one explain as to why this is so and is there any solution for this?

Comment: Both commands are  working properly ,which shell you are using bash or shell ?

Comment: You're probably using a bugged `date`. Try to make an update of it perhaps.

Comment: I am using the below version:- GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: That time is invalid because it falls in the hour skipped by the daylight savings time change, when the local time proceeds from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00. `zdump -v -c 2014,2015 <timezone>` will display the defined transition times for 2014 for you.

Comment: +1 what twalberg said. I had the same problem at the exact same date, and solved it by changing the TZ environment variable to a timezone without daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

The above command works fine without any issues in my HP UX B.11.11 version.

I was able to retrieve in the problematic date format too.